# List Customers That Purchased Orders > The Average Paid Order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following is my query:

```
select c.cust_lname, c.cust_fname, o.amount
from CUSTOMER c, orders o
where o.amount >
(select AVG (o.amount)
from orders o
group by order_num
having o.amount > AVG(o.amount));
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Well, what does "not working" even mean?

Comment: My fault, not working means not getting the right output.  I guess I should have been more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are writing the query, it would look like:

```
select c.cust_lname, c.cust_fname, o.amount
from CUSTOMER c join
     orders o
     on c.customerId = o.customerId
where o.amount > (select AVG (o.amount)
                  from orders o)
```

Note that you need to join together the two tables to get what you want.

Comment: Getting error:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'c'.

Comment: @JeffOrris . . . You need to connect the tables by the right field.  Replace `CustomerId` with whatever is the right field to connect those two tables.

Comment: The error message is because of another sloppy untested answer. Where is the `ON` keyword Gordon?

Comment: @GordonLinoff so now are you going to apologize to Jeff for making him seem like the one who was at fault?

Comment: @swasheck . . . When you consider that an entirely incorrect answer got two upvotes, I would think that you guys would have better things to do than gang up on me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nobody's ganging up. However you must admit that you often throw untested crap over the wall, and that blaming someone else just adds insult to injury.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The field in question was not in the original question.  I pointed out that the join was needed.  Even were I inclined, it would be hard to test something without the data formats.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's less about ganging up and 1) noting that you have a tendency, 2) watching that tendency play out is kinda fun. technically, your answer was entirely incorrect before the edit, too. btw, i didnt downvote and plan to upvote once the assumptions in your answer are validated by the OP.

Comment: I also did not down-vote. But the answer was not correct as originally posted; it was not valid syntax. This is something Management Studio can tell you even if you don't have the user's schema. But I suspect it's something you'll never try to do. In any case, if you post untested code in a hurry, and it's incorrect, please don't say people are ganging up on you. The whole point of this site is to help people solve their problems without also introducing problems you've created.

Comment: @swasheck . . . Are you saying that it was "entirely incorrect" because the `on` was left out of the `on` clause?  Or is there actually something wrong with the approach?

Comment: I like ponies and butterflies.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes. your statement wouldnt even parse.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I appreciate your comments more than you might imagine.  When I paste the query in SSMS, it looks just as bad with or without the `on` clause, because the tables are not defined -- pretty much the whole query registers as underlined errors in both cases.  BTW, in many cases, I actually do write the SQL in SSMS.

Comment: @JeffOrris . . . I'm glad I was able to help.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You overengineered it.  Take the having clause out of your subquery.

Comment: @JeffOrris you also need to remove the `group by` from the subquery (assuming you want the average of all orders)

Comment: These help, but the user is still going to get too many rows because they are using the old-fashioned "help me improve my odds of getting the Cartesian product" join syntax.

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.cust_lname, c.cust_fname, o.amount
from CUSTOMER c, orders o
where o.amount >
(select AVG (amount) from orders );
```

Comment: @JeffOrris this seems correct based on your question. care to elaborate why there are too many results?

Comment: There are only 13 orders, and I'm getting 45 results

Comment: indeed, you need to `join` the `customer` and `orders` tables, something like `from CUSTOMER c join ORDERS o on C.orderId = o.Id`